# Preserving domain of the expression under the limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Here is an easy starter question for you: what is the domain of the following function $f(x)$:
$$f(x) = \frac{x-2}{(x-2)(x-3)}$$
The correct answer to that is: $\text{dom}(f) = R \setminus{\left\{2, 3\right\}}$.

So my actual question is why then do we not have any problem computing the following limit:
$$\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{x-2}{(x-2)(x-3)} = \lim_{x\to 2} \frac{1}{(x-3)} = -1$$

I am asking because the symbol $$\lim_{x\to 2}$$ literally means "for all possible sequences $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n, \dots $with the limit of 2" and so some $x_i$ might be equal to $2$ which is sort of outside the domain of the expression under the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $\lim_{x\to 2} f(x) = L$ means for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that

$$0 < |x - 2| < \delta \ \Longrightarrow |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$$

This can be shown to be equivalent to a definition using sequences. But just as in the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition we exclude the case $x = 2$, no member of such a sequence can be equal to $2$.